# Gunicorn OpenBSD internal error

Tags: django, gunicorn, openbsd

with "gunicorn appname:application" shows worker running on 127.0.0.1.:8000 but when try to open at firefox or other browser shows me this error:

http://pastebin.com/s8g3WSBi

Comment: Yo need to show your configuration. What is 'application'?

Comment: https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central this is application with default configurations

Comment: I'm going to say you're Django settings are incorrect at a guess. Does it work if you run it through the test server?

Comment: Joe test server runs perfectly ..